# Date before 1970 in Typo3

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Is it possible to insert a date before 1970? I know, we life in an UNIX world but i need an workaround for my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you wanna to use such dates (which table and field?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timestamps pre-1970 in typo3 are negative.

Any date on or before September 1752 is not supported though due to the switch from Julian to Gregorian. If you need to go that far back then you're out of luck.

Comment: I need only a date range from 1950 - 2020

Comment: You're fine then. Use negatives for the pre 1970 dates.

Comment: The problem isn't in the database. The problem is in the ExtJS Validator for datetime. You can't enter a date before 1970. ExtJS will mark this field as invalid.